# Как сделать такой фон градиентом?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как сделать чтобы слово квартиры было с таким фоном ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так

> html

```
<div id="a">
Квартиры
</div>
```

> css

```
#a{
   heigth:100px;
   width:200px;
   padding:10px;
   background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, blue);
}
Цвета только подставь нужные
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую